# citação da mesma obra do mesmo autor e anos diferentes

Tags: latex, bibtex, abntex2

Olá. Recentemente comecei a usar LaTeX para escrever meus trabalhos. Gostaria de saber como posso citar a mesma obra do mesmo autor em anos diferentes, escrevendo algo como:

> Nameauthor(2009; 2017)

Estou usando `abntex2cite` e executando algo como:

```
\citeonline{nameauthor2009, nameauthor2017}
```

no entanto, isso não funciona para mim:

```
Nameauthor(2009), Nameauthor(2017).
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, mas aparentemente o que você pretende fazer é citar duas **edições** diferentes da mesma obra.

Se for isso mesmo, você deve criar duas entradas no seu arquivo `.bib` mudando apenas a *tag* de referencia e a **edição** da obra.

O exemplo abaixo seria para um livro.

```
@book{autor2009,
  author    = {Autor}, 
  title     = {Nome do livro},
  publisher = {Editora},
  year      = {ano},
  volume    = {volume},
  series    = {serie},
  address   = {Endereço},
  edition   = {**n° edição2009**},
  month     = {mês},
  note      = {Anotação},
  isbn      = {ISBN}
}
```

e

```
@book{autor2017,
  author    = {Autor}, 
  title     = {Nome do livro},
  publisher = {Editora},
  year      = {ano},
  volume    = {volume},
  series    = {serie},
  address   = {Endereço},
  edition   = {**n° edição2017**},
  month     = {mês},
  note      = {Anotação},
  isbn      = {ISBN}
}
```

e para citar você usa `\cite(autor2009)` e `\cite(autor2017)`.